# change last two digits to "00"

Tags: r

Suppose I have following data.frame:

```
dt=data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:5],code=c("101011,101102,101130","211011,101102",
  "101011,301102,101132","201015,401102,103412","131011,101101,105430"))

id                   code
A    101011,101102,101130
B           211011,101102
C    101011,301102,101132
D    201015,401102,103412
E    131011,101101,105430
F           101100,103200`
```

I hope the last two figures of code becoming "00", just like this:

```
id                   code
A    101000,101100,101100
B           211000,101100
C    101000,301100,101100
D    201000,401100,103400
E    131000,101100,105400
F           101100,103200`
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gsub` with `\\d{2}\\b`; Where `\\b` matches a word boundary, `\\d{2}\\b` thus matching two digits right before the word boundary; Use `gsub` to replace all matches with `00`:

```
dt$code <- gsub('\\d{2}\\b', '00', dt$code)

dt
#  id                 code
#1  A 101000,101100,101100
#2  B        211000,101100
#3  C 101000,301100,101100
#4  D 201000,401100,103400
#5  E 131000,101100,105400
```